# What is meaning of NO-HEAD in eclipse for android app?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am new to Android & eclipse. When I make a test project I can run it. Now when I delete it from eclipse and import again it's not work. because it's exist in my workspace.

For import I move them to another folder. Now When I open them through Option-> open existing android project then it's show me "NO-HEAD".

What it is and Why Every folder in my project have a icon (different) then previous. Can someone tell me about it. I have attached the image for explanation[image]. 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Eclipse has a version control plugin installed (probably Subclipse, a client plugin for subversion, or perhaps another one).

"NO HEAD" I believe means that Eclipse/Subclipse can no longer find the latest copy of your project since you moved it outside of there. If you right-click on one of those icons, you should discover some context menu commands that are version control-related.

Normally in Eclipse, you try to do as much as possible within its graphical interface, otherwise it can get confused when you delete/move/rename files outside of it. In those cases where you haven't done that, you often have to right click within the Eclipse project explorer and select "Refresh". And in those cases where a version control system is involved, it can be a bit more complex, but it's also a good sign because that means subversion probably kept a backup copy of that project (should you ever decide to revert what you just did).

Also whenever you import a project into Eclipse, it's a good idea to make a copy of it into your workspace, otherwise it can get confusing when you have to delete a project. As you must have found out already, Eclipse can be annoying when you delete a project (without deleting from disk) and when you immediately try to recreate another project by the same name in the same workspace.

That's the main reason I got into the habit of copying the contents of a project whenever I do an import. That way, I don't have to remember if I did, or did not make a copy, and if I have ever have to delete a project to start afresh, I don't need to worry about deleting the original source of what I've imported (even if tick the checkbox to also delete from disk).